# какой значение по умолчанию задать свойству longblob в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

имеется такая строка в таблице [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при попытке внести изображение в бд, выводит следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что делать в таком случае? помогите пожалуйста

Comment: В таком случае надо поставить отметку Null

Comment: @u_mulder получилось, спасибо большое)